# How to interpret Google Play Developer console Store listing conversion rate and percentiles comparisons?

Tags: google-analytics, statistics, google-play, google-play-console

I am trying to interpret the Store listing conversion rate metrics. Eg
given these metrics on Oct 19th my conversion rate was 9.3% while 50% of other apps had a 50.0% conversion rate?
25th percentile means, that 25% of apps had a 32.14% conversion rate? I would have expected some more detailed explanations with examples at https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859173?hl=en#zippy=%2Cdimensions

[image]

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question.  Rather, it is about Google Play Store analytics.

Comment: Thats great! Then where to ask?

Comment: I don't think there is a a Stack Exchange site that would be appropriate for this question.  I was going to suggest [android.se] but their [help](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says that questions about marketing and play store are off-topic there.